# Catching event when a control loses child control

Tags: vb.net, events, .net-4.5

Imagine this application in Vb.net, I have 2 panels and several buttons. I am moving buttons from a panel to other panel (through catching drag and drop events). I reached it.

Now I am trying the following:
Is there any way to raise an event from a panel when this panel loses some child button (or control)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel control doesn't seem to have an event that fires when its child control collection changes. [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The best thing to do would be handle this as part of the drop event. Presumably you have some code to determine if the button is to be moved. If this is true, call a function to do everything you want when a panel loses a control.

Comment: I see your point. Could I detect when parent changes of any control? Thanks!

Comment: for that you'd want to check the events of the control class which i think all controls inherit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

there is an event 'ParentChanged' which 'Occurs when the Parent property value changes.'

Answer (score 2):

Try this event when a control has added to the panel :

```
Private Sub Panel1_ControlAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs) Handles Panel1.ControlAdded

End Sub
```

And this when a control has removed :

```
Private Sub Panel1_ControlRemoved(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs) Handles Panel1.ControlRemoved

End Sub
```